# Radio button & Option list values migrate successfully with Feeds Importer but disappear in node edit

Tags: feeds

I'm doing a couple data migration projects. I'm using Feeds Importer and for the most part, things are going well.

But when I migrate option list fields, I get this weird thing where the data is migrated OK (I see it when I view the node and I see it in the appropriate table in the database), but when I edit the node, the option list field is empty/not-selected.

On one of the projects, I was using the radio button widget and the work-around ended up being changing the field's widget from that to Select list.

But on my second project, I was already using the Select List widget, and I can't seem to work around the problem. Tried changing it to radio buttons (hey - I'm not picky), but it didn't help.

It's a really sinister problem because it means I migrate the client's data OK, but when they edit one of these nodes, they will essentially delete data because the radio button or select list widget is not displaying the data. Help?

Comment: Did you go the field settings for that field and made sure that the values of the field list are present there?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, so I'm posting this as an answer.

I'd suggest that you install and enable the devel module to compare the data structure of the field in question in these three situations:

1. when the data is input manually
2. when the data is loaded via feeds
3. when the data loaded via feeds is later edited

If you haven't used it, with Devel installed, you can get the 'devel' view of the node.

Comment: Thanks, caelbtr! Good advice. I didn't actually use the devel module though it is great for many things. But I did set one of the fields manually and saved it so I could scrutinize it in the database. While doing that, I realized my mistake: I had a trailing space at the end of my key! So I had my Option list value settings like this:

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, caelbtr! Good advice. I didn't actually use the devel module (though it is great for many things).

But I did set one of the fields manually and saved it so I could scrutinize it in the database. While doing that, I realized my mistake: I had a trailing space at the end of my key! So I had my Option list value settings like this:

```
Yes |Yes
No |No
```

Changing it to...

```
Yes|Yes
No|No
```

...makes the migration (using Feeds Importer) work correctly.

It's fascinating that a trailing space would cause this behavior - but there you go! ; )