# Import data into Select List using using Feeds and the Feeds XML Parser from xml file

Tags: feeds

I have to import some data from a xml document.

I'm usuing the https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds and the https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_xpathparser modules.

I have other fields which get the data with no problem at all. But I can't get a **Select list** to get the data from the xml.

**XML LOOKS LIKE**

```
<properties>
  <property>
    <type>House</type>
  </property>

  <property>
    <type>Flat</type>
  </property>

  <property>
    <type>Parking</type>
  </property>
</properties>
```

**INFO OF THE field "Type" WHICH GET THE DATA:**

**Type:**

```
List (text)
```

**Control:**

```
Selection List
```

**Allowed values list:**

```
House|House
Flat|Flat
Parking|Parking
```

**THEN, IN THE FEED IMPORT SETTINGS:**

```
-MAPPING: add the xpathparser selecting the field "Type"
-XPHATH XML PARSER - Settings: set the XPath for the field to "Type"
```

As far as I see everything is all right, but it doesn't work.

I have other fields in the same importer which get the data with no problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on Drupal 7.x, you probably want to be using this module:

https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_ex

This is the new home for no-longer actively maintained one (https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_xpathparser)

I've been using feeds_ex and haven't had this problem.

Also, and I'm not sure about this, but I think the machine names for the list values should all be lowercase - but I could be wrong about this.

Comment: OK - I was wrong: case in the allowed values list doesn't matter, but I did have a problem like yours once and it was related to the allowed values list. I forgot until I just found this old question I posted. My problem was trailing spaces in the allowed values list: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/120157/radio-button-option-list-values-migrate-successfully-with-feeds-importer-but-d